# Как достать member из ctx.message.reference:?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Как достать member из ctx.message.reference:?
Вроде бы в {ctx.message.mentions[0].tag} пишется незнаю, помогите

```
if ctx.message.reference:
          image = random.choice(["https://media.giphy.com/media/143v0Z4767T15e/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/PHZ7v9tfQu0o0/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/GMFUrC8E8aWoo/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/svXXBgduBsJ1u/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/IRUb7GTCaPU8E/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/qscdhWs5o3yb6/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/lrr9rHuoJOE0w/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/LIqFOpO9Qh0uA/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/sUIZWMnfd4Mb6/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/3bqtLDeiDtwhq/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/3ZnBrkqoaI2hq/giphy.gif","https://media.giphy.com/media/ZQN9jsRWp1M76/giphy.gif"])
          embed = discord.Embed(title= '**Обнимашки** ❤️' ,description =f'{ctx.message.author.mention} **крепко обнял(а)** {ctx.message.mentions[0].tag} ',
          color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(138, 43, 226),timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
          embed.set_footer(text=f"\n\n{ctx.author.name} " ,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Объект `message.reference` имеет свойство, хранящее `id` сообщения, на которое ссылается данное сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имея `channel_id` можем получить канал, через который можно получить объект сообщения из `message_id`, а из него уже - упоминания (`message.mentions`):

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(ctx.message.reference.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
member = message.mentions[0]
```

Comment: А как это совместить в мой код?

Comment: Вопрос был в том, как получить упомянутого пользователя из старого сообщения, на которое ссылается текущее сообщение, так? Я привел вам 3 строчки, их которых вы получаете объект участника сервера, а что с ним делать дальше - решать вам. Как я понял, вам нужно просто добавить эти 3 строки в условие из вашего вопроса и потом заменить это `{ctx.message.mentions[0].tag}` на это `{member.mention}`

Comment: Не это я понял спасибо, мне что в if вводить

Comment: `if ctx.message.reference:`, затем мои три строки, а затем ваши, из вопроса. И не забудьте поменять это {ctx.message.mentions[0].tag} на это {member.mention}.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: У меня channel = bot.get_channel(ctx.message.reference.channel_id) светит красным

Comment: Почему? Какую-то причину же должна указывать среда разработки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132293/discussion-between-derzkiy-animeshnik-and-denisnumb).

Comment: Консоль ничего не выдает, но и код не работает