# Как мне можна реализовать роль мута?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы комманда работала на ответ сообщение то-есть человек написал плохое сообщение, админ ответил на сообщение командой .ban без тега и написало что Модер: ник Забанил: ник

````
@client.command(aliases=["м","m"])
async def мьют(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: str=None, reason=None):

    time_in_s = 0

    if time[len(time)-1:] == "с":
        time_in_s = int(time[:len(time)-1])

    elif time[len(time)-1:] == "м":
        time_in_s = int(time[:len(time)-1]) * 60

    elif time[len(time)-1:] == "ч":
        time_in_s = int(time[:len(time)-1]) * 60 * 60

    elif time[len(time)-1:] == "д":
        time_in_s = int(time[:len(time)-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24

    else:
        time_in_s = int(time[:len(time)-1])

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,id=864088962851012650)

    emb = discord.Embed(title='Вердикт', color=discord.Colour.gold())

    emb.add_field(name='Великий модератор', value=ctx.message.author.mention, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Замьютил', value=member.mention, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='По причине', value=reason, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='На', value=time, inline=False)

    await member.add_roles(role)

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb)

    await msg.add_reaction("✅")

    await asyncio.sleep(time_in_s)

    await member.remove_roles(role)```
````

Comment: И собственно, в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Вы недавно [спрашивали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1360333/373173) как работать со ссылкой на сообщение. Просто получите объект сообщения, как в примере из моего ответа и в качестве пользователя, которого нужно замьютить, возьмите автора полученного сообщения.